# Inactivate pyside-generated windows for the duration of background task

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

I have a simple gui application written in python with pyside. There is a main window and also some modal `QDialogs`. Depending on the user's actions in some of these dialogs, the application might have to connect to a database and perform corresponding tasks in it.
The problem is: database actions might take a few seconds to complete and my users tend to think that the program is stuck, so they start furiously clicking around and mashing keys. To prevent this erratic behavior I want to deactivate all the windows and display some loading symbol to calm things down.
What I need to create (left - normal state, right - busy state):

[image: Example of what is needed]

This is not the actual app, just an approximate schema of what I want to achieve.

I think some kind of `QMovie` should do the trick, but I have no idea how to cover a dialog with semi-transparent white and to display the loading symbol on top of it. I am also considering `QProgressBar`, but I am not sure if it's the right solution for the task.

I would appreciate any advice or a link to similar tasks solved (for some reason I was unable to google anything relevant myself, maybe I am using wrong keywords).

Comment: Have you tried setting the cursor to busy? `setCursor(QtCore.Qt.BusyCursor)`

Comment: Yeah, this _is_ a possible solution, but it's exactly what OS does when a program gets itself in trouble and hangs. So I think that might actually make the problem with users worse. I'd really like to see a customizable solution. To make clear the difference between the hung program and the busy one.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to cancel the process? How are you doing the database actions? in a different Thread? I had a similar problem with the GUI thread getting hung because I was processing in that thread and had to move the intensive process to another Thread.

Comment: Which OS? There is also the `QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor` which is more akin to the process being "hung" see here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#CursorShape-enum

Comment: @busfault I don't want to give users the ability to drop the task. This might lead to some really weird stuff in the DB, so I'd rather make them wait. Of course, I can't prevent them from blatantly killing the task, and that's one of the things I want to prevent by calming them with loading symbol. I do the database stuff in the same thread, mostly because the result of the database actions defines what the user will see in their GUI - It doesn't make sense to show outdated data - they get even more scared.

Comment: I think you will have to move it to another Thread regardless because your GUI will freeze unless you do. I'm betting that currently during that process the GUI gets weird, i.e. not refreshing. What I did with mine was to put a running timer showing that the process is running and a status showing what it is doing. I would only recommend using a Progress bar when you you can accurately predict the amount of time/data to process. If cancelling this task could corrupt the database, I would recommend, catching the closeEvent and giving a warning message to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the way you would do this is with some sort of progress indicator, either a `QProgressBar` or a `QProgressDialog`.

With the `QProgressDialog`, you can launch it modally to prevent users from interacting with the base `QDialog` or `QMainWindow`.

Either way, you should still be doing the slow-running task in another thread; otherwise, the GUI is just going to freeze.  The user won't be able to move the window or dialog, it won't respond to their clicks, and any progress updates you're making won't be shown in the GUI.